created_at comparison in Laravel Eloquent query
I have ths query which should return records that are created after "2024-04-19 21:00:47" but its not working some how please. Share if you have any idea ..
ChMessage::where(function ($q) use ($user_id) { 
    $q->where('from_id', 7)
      ->where('to_id', $user_id); 
})
->orWhere(function ($q) use ($user_id) { 
    $q->where('from_id', $user_id)
      ->where('to_id', 7);
})
->where("created_at",">","2024-04-19 21:00:47")->pluck("created_at")

here are my queries I tried..
I tried whereDate()
here I tried where()
I am expecting to get records that are created after 2024-04-19 21:00:47.. but its returning records before that timestamp as well..

i figured out that the date condition should be before the others.. and it worked for me :).
here is my query that works..
 ChMessage::where("created_at",">","2024-04-19 21:00:47")
     ->where(function ($q) use ($user_id) { 
         $q->where('from_id', 7)
           ->where('to_id', $user_id); 
     })
     ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($user_id) { 
         $q->where('from_id', $user_id)
           ->where('to_id', 7);
     })->pluck("created_at")

